# How to implement Facebook-style push notification in a web chat app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a web chat app using Spring with websocket & stomp. User A can chat with User B in real time. However, when A is not on the chat page with B, she cannot know new messages B sends to her. She needs some push notifications like these seen on Facebook. Since this push notification is a popular function, I am wondering if there is any sample code I can learn from. I have search for a few hours and have not found any in Spring yet.

[image]

Comment: You can use google fcm for push notification

Comment: @vipincp Unfortunately, Google is not accessible in some countries such as China, which my app plans to serve.